# PyJulia: %julia magic ignores local assigments

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I'm getting weird results when using the `%julia` magic inside of functions. Here is a minimal example (copied from the [documentation](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)):

```
import julia
%load_ext julia.magic

x = "global"

def f():
    x = "local"
    ret = %julia py"x"
    return ret

f()
```

Contrary to expectation, I get the result `'global'`. So it seems like all local assignment operations are ignored. Am I doing something wrong?